# ModuleNotFound error for astropy when running code

Tags: python, astropy, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to run some code in Spyder involving astropy. I installed the module, but it still says module not found: astropy whenever I run it. I don't know why it keeps returning this error. Here is the code (modified to protect information):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from astropy.io import ascii
from astropy import table
import astropy.io.fits as pyfits
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import units as u
import os
from function_file import *
import emcee
from scipy import stats
from scipy import ndimage
import mpfit
import re
import time
import pyfits
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import corner
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('/Users/myname/Desktop/Code/importantfunction.py'))
import importantfunction
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem so that we can help you. Can you share more information about the code you have written and the error you are getting?

Comment: Have you tried to install and use other modules the same way? Are you using Anaconda?

Comment: Hi! I am running the following code (which is for research, so I have changed some of the file names):

Comment: Please add this information to the question and not in the comment! :)

Comment: @explodingfilms101 I haven't tried to install and use other modules by command line installation, I have only had this error with astropy and no other module I'm trying to import in my code. I was using anaconda but I have separate issues with it (see my profile for the two questions I've asked related to it) - I'm currently using the standalone Spyder downloaded off their website.

Comment: So you're installing using pip?

Comment: conda, but to install astropy after I got the error the first time, I used pip install astropy.

Comment: The code here is not the issue. If you are having trouble installing a package the problem has to do with your environment, making sure you're running the correct tools for the correct Python and activating the correct paths in your IDE. It's not likely specific in any way to Astropy. Try searching for other [modulenotfounderror] questions. Usually these tend to have answers local to your personal setup that are difficult to reproduce or help anyone else in the future. We can try to help of course but I would suggest, if possible, finding someone local you can debug this with.